# Unity normalization with respect to bounded variables

Tags: normalization

I have some difficulties to normalize a number of variables, such that their normalized equivalents respect some boundaries constraints. Suppose I have two variables $-1\leq w_1\leq 1$ and $-1\leq w_2\leq 1$ where their sum is  $sum =w_1+w_2 \lneqq 1$, my purpose is to make the sum equal to $1$ such that the new variables respect the boundaries $[-1,1]$. Apparently, dividing by $sum$ does not solve the problem, because we could have $(w_1/sum) >1$. What kind of normalisation should I look in. Thank you.

Comment: If one of the w's is negative and your normalization scheme preserves signs, then surely after normalization one of them would exceed one. You may want to describe the background for us to better help you.

Comment: I am doing weighting on financial assets, the unity sum of weights means I invest all my money (is a constraint), while negative weights means short-selling for the corresponding asset. All my weights are constrained to respect some boundaries (-1 and 1). I use a program that sometimes return a sum of weights less than 1 in this context I would like to do normalization … Please tell me if this is not enough.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "respect some boundaries." After all, the variable $(w_1+w_2)/2$ will lie between $-1$ and $1$ (and has a possibility of attaining either endpoint), but surely you thought of this obvious solution, so what are you really looking for?

Comment: by "respect some boundaries" I mean that all the variables lie between -1 and 1 (before and after normalization) ... to answer your question I'm looking for a function that transform the sum of my variables to 1 such that the transform of each variable is between -1 and 1.